# How to add a button that jumps to an external link in the content type?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to add a purchase button in the content type, the button is an internal link, for example:www.example.com/go/nodeid. And then add an external purchase link to the text field, for example:https://item.jd.com/2385876.html. Click the buy button (internal link) JS jump to the external links, because I do not want to search engine crawling the external link address.
For example,
[image] open the page（http://www.chong4.com.cn/read.php?18818）, showing the link（http://www.chong4.com.cn/cydb/go.php?18818_127334_22s）, click will jump to（https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?id=536478627694&ali_trackid=2:mm_13376157_4604749_42838263,22s18818:1479362916_3k2_69258376）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **nofollow**: Links to an unendorsed document, like a paid link. ("nofollow" is used by Google, to specify that the Google search
>   spider should not follow that link)
>
> source: [HTML  rel Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp)

All you have to do is write your link like this:

`<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.example.com/something">Buy Now</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Implement the *internal link jump to external link* logic as per requirement. Now to avoid indexing of external links, you can install and configure [Noindex External Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/noindex_external_links) module.

> Module let's you take full control of external links indexing. Pages
>   could also pass HTML-validation.

Comment: A whole module just to add a nofollow property seems a bit heavy handed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module

Which allows you to redirec to external urls.

Answer (score -1):

For add links in content type you can use [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) module. That provide you link field.Add link field in your content type.[image]